# responsive not working in jwplayer

Tags: jwplayer

i use this code for jwplayer :

```html
<div id='myElement'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
playerInstance.setup({
image: "http://content.jwplatform.com/thumbs/PxnoM5gE-720.jpg",
sources: [{
file: "http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/PxnoM5gE-720.mp4",
label: "720p HD"
},{
file: "http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/PxnoM5gE-360.mp4",
label: "360p SD",
"default": "true"
},{
file: "http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/PxnoM5gE-180.mp4",
label: "180p Web"
}]
});
</script>
```

and worked . after add width: "50%", and aspectratio: "16:9" for responsive player not showing on website !

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to add commas after each option in your player? This worked in a page for me:

```
<div id='myElement'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
playerInstance.setup({
image: "http://content.jwplatform.com/thumbs/PxnoM5gE-720.jpg",
sources: [{
file: "http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/PxnoM5gE-720.mp4",
label: "720p HD"
},{
file: "http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/PxnoM5gE-360.mp4",
label: "360p SD",
// "default": "true"
},{
file: "http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/PxnoM5gE-180.mp4",
label: "180p Web"
}],
aspectratio: "16:9",
width: "50%"
});
</script>
```